# How can I add multiple actions to a UIButton

Tags: iphone

How can I add multiple action in a single UIButton? Life for example,

```
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(method1) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(method2) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

Thanks

Comment: Is something wrong with the code you pasted?  What's going on?

Comment: some of my question that I didn't accept the answer because some of them are right answers, so I just upvote them.

Comment: "... because some of them are right answers, so I just upvote them"  You really should pick and accept an answer.  We don't do this for fun!  We only do it for the point and the badges!  :)

Comment: If you ever have more than one correct answer, select the one that was better worded or helped you out the most.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The code you have pasted should work:

```
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(method1) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(method2) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

I do this all the time.  Usually for touchDown and touchUp.  The fact that method2 isn't getting called is a bug.  Do you have an NSLog() at the beginning of method2?

Comment: This is really not a scaleable solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(method1and2) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

…   

- (void)method1and2 {
    [self method1];
    [self method2];
}
```

Comment: But he has 2 different events?  This is what I thought first also, but it doesn't work for the question.